# How to remove window._nuxt_ in nuxt project, it is too large for me

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-ssr

When I use `nuxt` to develop my project, I find some problems.

```
window.__NUXT__=(function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,_,$,aa, ..... code was too larger
```

can I remove it or use js file to replace it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a relatively perfect solution. I will share it with you here. You can also take a look at the website I developed using NUXT [Sample Website](https://www.reasonbox.com)

The key is the `hook` function `vue-renderer:ssr:context`, you can set the `context.nuxt = null` to remove any data in `window._NUXT_`.

But it is not work well, you have to add `serverRender` and `routePath` to `window.nuxt`

```
// nuxt.config.js
{
...,
hooks: {
    'vue-renderer:ssr:context'(context) {
      const routePath = JSON.stringify(context.nuxt.routePath);
      context.nuxt = {serverRendered: true, routePath};
    }
  }
}
```

You can see the result at [my site](https://www.reasonbox.com)

Comment: You're a live saver :)