# How to remove window.__NUXT__ without any issue from Vuex in Nuxt

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-render-function

I'm on Nuxt 2.13 and I'm having an issue with `window.__Nuxt__(function(a,b,c,d,.....))`. I don't know if it will affect my SEO or not, but it's on my nerve and shows all my language file.

here is the situation : there is a `lang.json` file in my app. i read it and store it in a `lang` state in `Vuex`. but `window.__Nuxt__` shows my lang which i don't want to!!

i have found three solutions so far to remove it:

1: by adding this code to nuxt.config.js
[link to stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082751/how-to-remove-window-nuxt-in-nuxt-project-it-is-too-large-for-me)

```js
hooks: {
    'vue-renderer:ssr:context'(context) {
      const routePath = JSON.stringify(context.nuxt.routePath);
      context.nuxt = {serverRendered: true, routePath};
    }
  }
}
```

2: by commenting some codes in `node_module/@nuxt/vue-renderer/dist/vue-renderer.js`
[link to article](https://programmersought.com/article/86373709392/)

3: by using cheerio package and scraping the script from body
[link to article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/97204763548/)

```js
const cherrio = const cheerio = require('cheerio');
export default {
//The rest configuration is omitted
hooks: {
    'render:route': (url, result) => {
      this.$ = cheerio.load(result.html,{decodeEntities: false});
      //Since window.__nuxt__ is always located in the first script in the body,
      //So I removed the first script tag in the body
      this.$(`body script`).eq(0).remove();
      result.html = this.$.html()
    }
  }
}
```

all three will do the job, BUT !! my components won't be lazy loaded anymore as i use an state in Vuex to give theme address for lazy load! for example:

```js
computed:{
  mycomponent(){
    return ()=>import(`~/components/${this.$store.state.siteDirection}/mycomp.vue`)
  }
}
```

it will give error that webpack cant lazy load this as `this.$store.state.siteDirection` is null.

how can i solve this??

Comment: By any chance, did you find a solution?

Comment: @MostafaSaid , unfortunately no. apparently that's how `state management` works. I just changed my lang structure by using `i18n`.